# Compiling and linking library MSVC/MingW

Tags: qt, g++, mingw

I'm a big fan of StackOverflow because you always have answers for problems, and now is my chance to get advance of it Ö!

I'm trying to use a library which I got in the Internet, its OZCollide. Its suppossed to be crossplatform as it says in its website "*Cross-platform, works on Windows, Linux and Macintosh, in fact any platform supporting VisualStudio 6/7 or gcc*"

I got all the .h and .cpp, compile them with MinGW as objects (.o) and then link them all using ar. But the problem is when I include and use the library on my project (QT & MinGW) it throws "undefined reference".

I thought the problem could be that library examples only uses Visual Studio, so the library coulnd't be compiled for MinGW, but the website tells other story.

Thanks for your time!

---

**EDIT:** Okay I have managed to compile it and use it moving to another computer and compiling makefile. The only one difference is that Computer A had Cygwing and MinGW installed (with Cygwin set up in Windows path) and Computer B only had MinGW.

So I guess the problem was Makefile calling for g++ and Cygwin g++ got called instead of MinGW g++??

If I'm right, whats the difference between Cygwin and MinGW?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have experience with CMake, create your own CMakeLists file and import/link this libraries against your project. In this way, you can create projects for MinGW/MSVC/Linux/etc.

Here you'll find a good start with CMake http://www.cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/

Comment: Well, to be honest I'm hard learning to deal with g++, makefile, etc because its my first time and the Makefile included in the library wasn't working. But I'll give a try to your link.

Comment: With CMake, you don't have to care about the single compiler. 
CMake will setup for you a g++ Makefile, a MSVC .sln, depending on which platform/compiler is installed on your machine and link all the libraries you want against your application.
No more headaches!